# Stock Android - Block USSD Balance Update Pop Up Messages

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, smsmanager, ussd

I am trying to build and flash a custom rom for Nexus 6p. One of the things I am trying to do is block the USSD Balance update pop up messages that show up after sending a message, making a call and data usage. This happens on a prepaid cellular connection and I want to block these USSD messages from appearing. I am going through the Marshmallow stock Android source code but am struggling to find the relevant classes where the changes need to be incorporated.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.